# ColumnTransformer inside a Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm building a pipeline in scikit-learn. I have to do different transformations with different features, and then standardize them all. So I built a `ColumnTransformer` with a custom transformer for each set of columns:

```
transformation_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ('adoption', TransformAdoptionFeatures, features_adoption),
    ('census', TransformCensusFeaturesRegr, features_census),
    ('climate', TransformClimateFeatures, features_climate),
    ('soil', TransformSoilFeatures, features_soil),
    ('economic', TransformEconomicFeatures, features_economic)
],
    remainder='drop')
```

Then, since I'd like to create two different pipelines to both standardize and normalize my features, I was thinking of combining `transformation_pipeline` and the scaler in one pipeline:

```
full_pipeline_stand = Pipeline([
    ('transformation', transformation_pipeline()),
    ('scaling', StandardScaler())
])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object is not callable
```

Is there a way to do this without building a separate pipeline for each set of columns (combining the custom transformer and the scaler)? That is obviously working but is just looks like useless repetition to me... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I spot my error, I was switching the instantiation of the classes: the custom transformers have to be instantiated inside the `ColumnTransformer`, while the `ColumnTransformer` does not have to be instantiated inside the pipeline.

The correct code is the following:

```
transformation_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ('adoption', TransformAdoptionFeatures(), features_adoption),
    ('census', TransformCensusFeaturesRegr(), features_census),
    ('climate', TransformClimateFeatures(), features_climate),
    ('soil', TransformSoilFeatures(), features_soil),
    ('economic', TransformEconomicFeatures(), features_economic)
],
    remainder='drop')

full_pipeline_stand = Pipeline([
    ('transformation', transformation_pipeline),
    ('scaling', StandardScaler())
])
```